# Incorrect RSA1 identifier , Could not load “/root/.ssh/id_rsa” as a RSA1 public key : SSH denied

Tags: ssh, login, rsa

I am able to ping the server in question (172.16.110.138) but can't connect via SSH

Observed error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh -vvv 172.16.110.138
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.110.138 [172.16.110.138] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
**debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
*****debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier**
**debug3: Could not load "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key*******
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
```

Also, telnet at port 22 is connecting

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet 172.16.110.138 22 Trying 172.16.110.138... 
Connected to 172.16.110.138. Escape character is '^]'.
```

Is there any way to access this server? Like forcibly sending a reboot via SSH/Telnet etc. since the server is at remote location and cant access the same via any console.